# SwiftUI - Button action draws on an image

Tags: ios, image, button, swiftui, action

Hobbyist ios coder here...

I have an old Objective C project I am trying to recreate in swiftui.

When I click a button, it draws a CGRect and fills in the peramiters of image source from the IBAction I wrote out that i can then drag arround the screen.

[Old way I used to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onyze.png)

How do i do this in SwiftUI?

[My empty SwiftUI Button Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGgDv.png)

I currently have an image drawn within a VStack that I can move arround and resize, but I want it to not exist on app load, but for it and others to be drawn on user request. IE button press.

I have no idea what it is im supposed to search for to find this answer as searching for button and image instantly gives me tutorials on how to add images to a button, not a button that draws a fresh interactable element on the view.

Thank you to anyone who can shed more light on this.

EDIT - On pressing the button a second time I need the image to spawn again so there would be multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand this correctly, but it's simply a matter of displaying an image when a button is clicked?

You already said that you got an image with the desired behavior, but you don't want it to be there from the beginning. I think you are looking for an alternative in SwiftUI for `addSubview`, but there is no direct one.

What you might be looking for is `@State` in SwiftUI. Changing a `@State` variable will force your view to redraw itself. (There are more then just `@State` variables that to this)

You can draw your Image based on a condition. On your button click you could change the state variable that your condition is based on to redraw your view and to display your Image. I use the toggle() function in my example, so clicking the Button a second time will result in removing the image.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showImage = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showImage {
                Image(systemName: "gear") // Your working image
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.showImage.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("draw image")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example how you could add more and more Images when clicking the button again and again. I changed the Type of the `@State` variable to an array and then iterate over that array via a `ForEach`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var images: [UUID] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(images, id: \.self) { _ in
                Image(systemName: "gear") // Your working image
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.images.append(UUID())
            }, label: {
                Text("draw image")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.This would do as i need, except the complicated part is, when the button is touched again I would like a second instance of the same image to also be spawned.

My appologies for not mentioning this in the origonal post.

Comment: It would work the same. You would change the State type from bool to array, change the if condition to a ForEach(state array) and on button click you would add a new element to your array :)

Comment: This might help: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-add-rows-list-tutorial

Comment: Thank you so much. You have gone above and beyond. So I can understand further can you please write it out? If not thats ok, you have helped more than I expected! :)

Comment: I updated my original answer to reflect the ForEach approach. :) Don't forget to mark the question as answered :) 
I would also recommend checking out the official SwiftUI Tutorial that apple released, its great! 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: You Legend. Thank you! :)